# Is it possible to multiply the items in a list by a constant?

Tags: scala

Consider the following code (which is incorrect for now) :

```
def sum_of_products(weights: Seq[Double], points: Seq[Seq[Double]]) : Seq[Double] = {
  weights.zip(points).map((weight, point) => weight * point).sum
}
```

My `point` is a `Seq[Double]`. By the way, I would want to multiply a `point` by its associated `weight` ("associated" because both are present in the same couple).

So, how to multiply a `Seq[Double]` by a `Double` ? I think I can't use `map` since it would return a `Seq[Double]`. Thus, the below code seems to be incorrect :

```
def sum_of_products(weights: Seq[Double], points: Seq[Seq[Double]]) : Seq[Double] = {
  weights.zip(points).map((weight, point) => point.map(coordinate => weight * coordinate)).sum
}
```

Indeed, here I am transforming my `(weight, point)` into a `Seq[Double]`. But I want to transform it into a `Double`.

I am working on linear interpolation.

SOLUTION (i.e. : implementation of a component of linear interpolation in `n` dimensions) :

```
def sum_of_products(weights: Seq[Double], points: Seq[Seq[Double]]) : Seq[Double] = {
  weights.zip(points).map(
    weight_point => weight_point._2.map(coordinate => weight_point._1 * coordinate)
  ).reduce((point_a : Seq[Double], point_b : Seq[Double]) => point_a.zip(point_b).map(coordinate_points => coordinate_points._1 + coordinate_points._2))
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use `my_seq.map(e => 4*e)` ?

Comment: I edited my post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use case syntax for expanding the tuple in a map with curly braces

```
weights.zip(poDoubles).map{case(weight, poDouble) => weight * poDouble}
```

Now, if you multiply a sequence of Double to a Double you'll end up with a resultant Seq of Double as every element of the sequence will be multiplied by the given double. You can do:

Either return Seq[Seq[Double]] and operate on the result accordingly

```
def sumOfProducts(weights: Seq[Double], points: Seq[Seq[Double]]): Seq[Seq[Double]] =
  weights.zip(points).map{case (weight, point) => point.map(coordinate => weight * coordinate)}
```

Or use a flatmap which will flatten your sequence and return Seq[Double]

(*Seq(Seq(1.0, 2.0, 3.0), Seq(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)) will be Seq(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0)*)

```
def sumOfProducts(weights: Seq[Double], points: Seq[Seq[Double]]) : Seq[Double] =
  weights.zip(points).flatMap{case (weight, point) => point.map(coordinate => weight * coordinate)}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I edited my post to offer the solution I found

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
weights.zip(points).map((weight, point) ...
```

`map` takes a function from a 2-tuple to some type `T`, but your code is passing to `map` a function that takes 2 inputs, which is different than a 2-tuple. Here is a correct implementation of the function:

```
def sum_of_products(weights: Seq[Double], points: Seq[Seq[Double]]) : Seq[Double] = {
    weights.zip(points).map { 
         case (weight, point) =>
             point.map(coordinate => weight * coordinate).sum 
    }
}
```

The key is adding the word `case` inside the map so you can use pattern matching to extract `weight` and `point` from the 2-tuple. This is functionally equivalent to:

```
def sum_of_products(weights: Seq[Double], points: Seq[Seq[Double]]) : Seq[Double] = {
    weights.zip(points).map { 
         wp =>
             wp._2.map(coordinate => wp._1 * coordinate).sum 
    }
}
```